# Control-Option-<arrow> hotkey not working in tmux

Tags: iterm, keybindings, tmux

I'm using tmux over iTerm2 in Mac OS 12.5.

I have such directives in tmux config file:

```
# resizing panes using Ctrl-Alt-arrows without prefix
bind -n C-M-Up resize-pane -U 2
bind -n C-M-Down resize-pane -D 2
bind -n C-M-Left resize-pane -L 10
bind -n C-M-Right resize-pane -R 10
bind -n C-M-k resize-pane -U 2
bind -n C-M-j resize-pane -D 2
bind -n C-M-h resize-pane -L 10
bind -n C-M-l resize-pane -R 10

# switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D
```

`C-M-{h,j,k,l}` and `M-{Left,Right,Up,Down}` are working as expected, but for some reason `C-M-{Left,Right,Up,Down}` are not working at all. But on Windows machine under WSL the same config works fully as expected.

Is it some kind of global Mac OS keybinding? But looks like it does nothing. Is there a way to make it work for tmux?

Comment: Does this: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator#add-a-snippet help you?

Comment: @Yoan, sorry, but I don't see how it can help with my situation:(